# error:04099079:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_OAEP_mgf1:oaep decoding error

Tags: php, openssl, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to decrypt a JWE token, and I'm getting an error when decrypting the private key of the token with a PCKS1 certificate.

`error:04099079:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_OAEP_mgf1:oaep decoding error`

The header of the decrypted token is as follows:
{"alg":"RSA-OAEP-256","kid":"2022-12-01","iss":"https://test.com","typ":"JWE","exp":"1698311253766","enc":"A256CBC-HS512"}

The PHP code I am using openssl is as follows:

```
$token = 'eyJhbGciO...';

list($header, $encryptedKey, $iv, $cipherText, $authTag) = explode('.', $token);

$header = $this->base64url_decode($header);
$encryptedKey = base64_decode($encryptedKey);
$iv = $this->base64url_decode($iv);
$cipherText = $this->base64url_decode($cipherText);
$authTag = $this->base64url_decode($authTag);

$privateKeyPEM = file_get_contents("/prkey.pem");
$privateKey = openssl_pkey_get_private($privateKeyPEM);


if(!openssl_private_decrypt($encryptedKey, $decryptedKey, $privateKey, OPENSSL_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING))
{
   while ($msg = openssl_error_string())
   var_dump($msg);die;
}

$plainText = openssl_decrypt($cipherText, 'aes-256-cbc', $encryptedKey,OPENSSL_RAW_DATA , $iv, $authTag);
```